# Detect when no previous posts available in Facebook Graph posts edge?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm accessing the Facebook Graph API for posts and am trying to figure out the pagination handling. I understand the use of paging.next and paging.previous properties of the results but I'd like to know when there are actually previous results. Particularly, when I make the first 'posts' call, I get back a paging.previous url even though there are no previous values. Upon calling that url I get a response with no results.

For example, calling "168073773388372/posts?limit=2" returns the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "story": "Verticalmotion test added a new photo.",
      "created_time": "2015-12-02T17:04:56+0000",
      "id": "168073773388372_442952469233833"
    },
    {
      "message": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD2Rdeo8vuE",
      "created_time": "2013-12-16T23:19:30+0000",
      "id": "168073773388372_184840215045061"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/168073773388372/posts?limit=2&format=json&since=1449075896&access_token=****&__paging_token=enc_AdA69SApv4VoBZB0PPZA7W5EivCYQal8KMFmRNkyhr8ZBk4w0YmFEQUJWV3JZBS70ihyMpbqieQaERhY50enqNCMBuIZATadeopYj8xPvQL7Y8KueaQZDZD&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/168073773388372/posts?limit=2&format=json&access_token=****&until=1387235970&__paging_token=enc_AdAVMaUlPmpxjBmq5ZClVdNpFp7f9MyMFWjE7ygqsMLW7zvSx3eGHLkfwDxdCx0uO3ooAZCKDmCwMWHZA9RNyxkYUPJyjMtO3kynKm5uF2PhoPZB2gZDZD"
  }
}
```

How can I tell if it's the first set of results?

From tidbits scattered around the documentation and web, it seems like the previous url shouldn't be there.

I don't think it matters because I get the same results in the Graph Explorer but I'm using OpenFB to access the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the order to be reverse then get the 1st result

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

**Ordering**

You can order certain data sets chronologically. For example you may sort a photo's comments in reverse chronological order using the key reverse_chronological:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /{photo-id}?
    fields=comments.order(reverse_chronological)
```

order must be one of the following values:

```
*chronological*
*reverse_chronological*
```

Comment: You just need order reverse by created_time

Comment: And you just need the 1st post then make compare to get if there is no post!

Comment: Thanks Minh! So to make sure I'm understanding, get the posts in reverse chronological order, record the first one and use it when paging to compare against the first result I get back and if it matches, there are no previous results? Wouldn't this fail if new posts had been added? Not that this is critical but I was hoping for a more "built-in" method.

Comment: In the facebook document said: 
previous : The Graph API endpoint that will return the previous page of data. If not included, this is the first page of data.

Comment: Unfortunately it only says it's not included for Cursor and Offset-based paging. The feed and posts edges seem to use Time-based paging which seem to always include a previous Url.

Comment: Marking as answer as there doesn't seem to be a better way to do this.